# React-Admin- ArrayInput/SimpleFormIterator- How to identify and pass current record to custom component

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

Please I am having an issue with accessing and passing current record I am working with when there are more than one records in the Array:

For example: see the json below: the whole array *salesoutdet* is being passed irrespective of which index I am on.

```json
{
  "id":1
  "salesoutdet": [
    {
      "unitprice": 10,
      "quantity": 5,
      "total": 50
    },
    {
      "unitprice": 2,
      "quantity": 1,
      "total": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

See my ArrayInput below. The custom component (TotalField) is embedded. This should pass only the current record but it passing all the records of the SimpleFormIterator. Please how can I achieve this?

```js
<ArrayInput source="salesoutdet" validate={[required()]}>
  <SimpleFormIterator>
    <ReferenceInput label="Sku" source="sku" reference="products">
      <SelectInput optionText="name" />
    </ReferenceInput>
    <NumberInput label="Quantity" source="quantity" />
    <NumberInput label="Unit Price" source="unitprice" />

    <FormDataConsumer>
      {({
        formData, // The whole form data
        scopedFormData, // The data for this item of the ArrayInput
        getSource, // A function to get the valid source inside an ArrayInput
        ...rest
      }) => {
        //console.log(`getSource: ${JSON.stringify(scopedFormData)}`)
        return scopedFormData ? <TotalField source={getSource('total')} record={scopedFormData} {...rest} /> : null;
      }}
    </FormDataConsumer>
  </SimpleFormIterator>
</ArrayInput>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way it works actually.

`scopedFormData` contains all the records for the array's scope. That's why you have to pass the `source` through the `getSource` handler so that you assign the correct array index on each iteration.

What exactly is your questions?

Provide us with the `TotalField` component if you need further help in displaying the correct data.